# Using wp_insert_post() with Networking enabled

Tags: multisite, wp-insert-post

I'm working on a script that will drop articles directly into the wordpress database, using [wp_insert_posts().](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) However, I have [networking](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) enabled and the [wp_insert_post() reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) has no documentation relating to using wp_insert_post() to upload to a specific site on the network.

How can I do this with wp_insert_posts()? Or is their another function which does this?

Comment: Why not to use [switch_to_blog](http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/switch_to_blog) in order to insert your posts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using function like `wp_insert_post()` It will work on the currently active blog, meaning that if you are on a blog in your network with blog_id of 2 the the post you insert using  `wp_insert_post()`  will be inserted to that blog.

Now if you want to insert the post to a specific blog you can use `switch_to_blog()` function which will tell WordPress that "the current blog is" so you can use `wp_insert_post()` to insert to that specific blog.

Then to tell WordPress that what is the real current blog you can use `restore_current_blog()` so:

```
switch_to_blog($wanted_blog_ID);
...
...
your wp_insert_post() stuff
...
...
restore_current_blog();
```

take a look at [**WPMU Functions**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WPMU_Functions) to understand more about the available functions in a network.

Comment: I realize this answer is older than React.js, but I am currently having a giant problem with switch_to_blog. I've asked a question here, if you don't mind taking a look? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/388622/wpmu-programmatically-adding-cpt-posts-to-specific-blog-id