# WPMU: Programmatically adding CPT posts to specific blog id

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite

I'm trying to programmatically add press releases from an API, to specific sub sites (blog ID's).

The application is quite large, but I've boiled it down for the purposes of this question. It runs outside of WP Core, only loading it while running, through `wp-load.php`.

```
require_once( "../wp-load.php" );

$blog_id = 2;
switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
$lang = 'en';

$new_pr = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => 'pressreleases',
        'post_date'         => $this->publish_date,
        'post_content'      => $this->body,
        'post_title'        => $this->title,
        'tax_input'         => array(
            'pr_categories'     => $this->pr_category_id
        )
    )
);
var_dump( get_current_blog_id() ); // This returns (int)2, just like it should.
restore_current_blog();
```

Here's the problem:
No matter what I put in the `$blog_id` variable, the release gets added to the blog with ID `1`.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself. It's two parts:

1. I need the global `$switched` to be defined.
2. The variable for blog id can't be `$blog_id` because that's reserved.

The above code should thus be the following.

```php
require_once( "../wp-load.php" );

global $switched;
$blog_id_target = 2;
switch_to_blog($blog_id_target);

$lang = 'en';

$new_pr = wp_insert_post(
    array(
        'post_author'   => 1,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => 'pressreleases',
        'post_date'         => $this->publish_date,
        'post_content'      => $this->body,
        'post_title'        => $this->title,
        'tax_input'         => array(
            'pr_categories'     => $this->pr_category_id
        )
    )
);
var_dump( get_current_blog_id() ); // This returns (int)2, just like it should.
restore_current_blog();
```